# PLSQL - stored procedure with API call not valid

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have the following stored procedure, doing an API call and then inserting the response as a Clob in a target table:

```
create or replace procedure api_call(
       time_id       in varchar2,
       repository    in varchar2,
       api_query     in varchar2)
       as
       
       date_from varchar2 := to_char(to_date(time_id, 'yyyymmdd', 'nls_date_language = English'));
       date_to varchar2 := to_char(to_date(time_id, 'yyyymmdd', 'nls_date_language = English') + 1);
       
       req                utl_http.req;
       res                utl_http.resp;
       response_json      clob;
       url varchar2(2000) := 'url/'||repository||'/query';
       
       query_string varchar2(4000) := '{"queryString":"'||api_query||'","start":'||date_from||',"end":'||date_to||', "isLive":false}';

begin
       DBMS_LOB.createtemporary(response_json, false);
       
       req := utl_http.begin_request(url, 'POST', ' HTTP/1.1');
       utl_http.set_header(req, 'Authorization: Bearer', 'someAPItoken');
       utl_http.set_header(req, 'content-type', 'application/json');
       utl_http.set_header(req, 'Accept', 'application/json');
       
       utl_http.write_text(req, query_string);
       
       res := utl_http.get_response(req);
       
       begin
         loop
           utl_http.read_text(res);
           DBMS_LOB.writeappend(response_json);
         end loop;
       exception
         when utl_http.end_of_body then
           utl_http.end_response(res);
         end;
         
         insert into http_response_table (time_id, repository, json_data)
         values (time_id, repository, response_json);
         
         DBMS_LOB.freetemporary(reponse_json);
         
       exception
         when others then
           utl_http.end_response(res);
           DBMS_LOB.freetemporary(reponse_json);
           raise;

end api_call;
```

For some reason, when trying to test the procedure, it claims the object is invalid. Although it creates the stored procedure without any error messages.

Any ideas what is wrong in the stored procedure? Formatting- or syntax-wise?

Comment: Please check for errors in `select * from user_errors`

Comment: Comes back as empty

Comment: How about in `all_errors` or `dba_errors` (if you can see that), in case you don't own it? And please edit your question to show how you call it and the exact output you get.

Comment: Thanks, it shows up in all_errors!

Comment: What development tool are you using? You need to become familiar with however it reports compilation errors, otherwise PL/SQL development is going to be very painful.

Answer (score 0):

Your code has lots of issues. When you create a procedure, Oracle will tell you if it has an issue "Warning: Procedure created with compilation errors."
So, you ask for the errors by doing a
SQL> show err

Then you rectify them one by one. For example, in your code, you have a variable called response_json, and you refer to it as such or as reponse_json. So rectify this. Then you'll get an error about dbms_lob.writeappend not having the required params, rectify that, and see if there any any remaining ones, ....

Answer (score 0):

Putting your code into a [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=79e311cd826691bd24ade258c53228ed) and then running:

```sql
SELECT * FROM USER_ERRORS;
```

Gives the errors:

> | NAME | TYPE | SEQUENCE | LINE | POSITION | TEXT | ATTRIBUTE | MESSAGE_NUMBER |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | API_CALL | PROCEDURE | 1 | 7 | 18 | PLS-00215: String length constraints must be in range (1 .. 32767) | ERROR | 215 |
> | API_CALL | PROCEDURE | 2 | 8 | 16 | PLS-00215: String length constraints must be in range (1 .. 32767) | ERROR | 215 |
> | API_CALL | PROCEDURE | 3 | 31 | 12 | PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'READ_TEXT' | ERROR | 306 |
> | API_CALL | PROCEDURE | 4 | 31 | 12 | PL/SQL: Statement ignored | ERROR | 0 |
> | API_CALL | PROCEDURE | 5 | 32 | 12 | PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'WRITEAPPEND' | ERROR | 306 |
> | API_CALL | PROCEDURE | 6 | 32 | 12 | PL/SQL: Statement ignored | ERROR | 0 |
> | API_CALL | PROCEDURE | 7 | 42 | 33 | PLS-00201: identifier 'REPONSE_JSON' must be declared | ERROR | 201 |
> | API_CALL | PROCEDURE | 8 | 42 | 10 | PL/SQL: Statement ignored | ERROR | 0 |
> | API_CALL | PROCEDURE | 9 | 47 | 35 | PLS-00201: identifier 'REPONSE_JSON' must be declared | ERROR | 201 |
> | API_CALL | PROCEDURE | 10 | 47 | 12 | PL/SQL: Statement ignored | ERROR | 0 |

You need to fix them all for the package to compile and be valid.